# Click on pause can‘t get respond when download

Tags: android

When I download,click on pause,but there isn't respond.
I don't konw how to description specific,in fact it is meaning stop,but really can't realize.
the code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                      [color=#FF0000]if (flag == 0){//click mark[/color]
```

can't display,the red is only a mark.
code as follows

```
holder.btns .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                  [color=#FF0000]if (flag == 0){//judge the click mark[/color] 

                    holder.ratingBarScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                    }else {
//                        Toast.makeText(this, "there is no SD card", 1000).show();
                        Log.v("wjp", "7889900");
                    }
                    final String downloadUrl =(String)v.getTag();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        int count = 0;
                        public void run(){
                          Log.v("ccf", "onClick");
                          try {
                              downLoadFile(context, downloadUrl, gameName, holder);    
                              openFile(context, new File("/sdcard/9twan/"+ gameName +".apk"));
                              if(!WebHelper.REGISTER_FLAG){
                                  Log.v("GamesInfoListAdapter", "WebHelper.REGISTER_FLAG == false");
                                  String imei, mac, mobile_number, model, brand;
                                  boolean flag;
                                  TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                                  imei = tm.getDeviceId();
                                  if(imei == null){
                                      imei = "CUSTOM" + WebHelper.generateRandomIMEIString(15);
                                  }
                                  mac = null;
//                                  mac = tm.getDeviceId(); 
                                  if(mac == null){
                                      mac = "CUSTOM" + WebHelper.generateRandomMacString(17);
                                  }
                                  mobile_number = tm.getLine1Number();
                                  model = tm.getLine1Number();
                                  brand = tm.getLine1Number();
                                  flag = WebHelper.regDevice(context, "install", imei, mac, mobile_number, model, brand);
                                  if(flag){
                                      WebHelper.REGISTER_FLAG = true;
                                      Log.v("GamesInfoListAdapter", "WebHelper.REGISTER_FLAG == true");
                                  }
                              }

                          }catch (Exception e){
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                        }
                    };
                    Log.v("wjp", "running"+thread.getName());
                    thread.start();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "begin to download" + gameName, 0).show();
                    holder.btns.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_out);

                    [color=#FF0000]flag =1;[/color]//here is need to pause,how to write?
                    }else {
                          if(Thread.currentThread() !=null){
                              Thread.interrupted();
//                              Thread = null;
                          }
//                        thread.
//                        Thread.interrupted();//pause return boolean
//                        Thread.sleep(3000);
//                          Thread.

                        holder.btns.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_install);
                        flag =0;

                    }
                }

            });
        }
        return convertView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to interrupt the current thread, You should interrupt the thread you have started. Also are you changing the value of flag. You seem to have multiple variables named flag

```
if(thread !=null){
 thread.interrupt();      
}
```